# How to find the outcomes/probability of Heads at $i$th position of a coin tossed $n$ times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A fair coin is tossed $n$ times. The sample space is the space of ordered binary vectors of length $n$. A $1$ in the $i$th position of such a binary vector indicates Heads at the $i$th toss. Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i$th toss is Heads, $i=1,...n$.

What would be the number of outcomes in $A_i$? Is the total number of outcomes $2^n$?

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of outcomes for the sample space"?

Comment: The total number of outcomes? $|\Omega|$?

Comment: OK – but then what do you mean by "the number of outcomes for $A_i$"? You seem to be using the expression "the number of outcomes for" in two different senses?

Comment: I am looking for $|A_i|$. Does this make sense?

Comment: It does. I think the conventional way to express that would be "the number of outcomes *in* $A_i$".

Comment: Thank you. Will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that there are $2^n$ outcomes in the sample space. By symmetry, exactly half of these have heads in any given position. Thus $|A_i|=\frac12\cdot2^n=2^{n-1}$. Alternatively, you can count the possibilities in the remaining $n-1$ positions; these are $n-1$ independent binary choices, so again $2^{n-1}$ possibilities.

Comment: @PLC: Indeed. Though you didn't have to go through the detour of $2^n$ outcomes to conclude that the probability for a given toss to result in heads is $\frac12$. In fact, that's doing things the wrong way around, in a sense: You're assuming (or the problem's author is assuming) that the $2^n$ outcomes are equiprobable, and deriving from this that the two results of an individual toss are equiprobable. But the main intuition is not that the $2^n$ outcomes are equiprobable, but that each toss is equally likely to yield heads or tails, and that the different tosses are independent.

Comment: So it would actually make more sense to go the other way, assume that $P(A_i)=\frac12$ and that the $A_i$ are independent, and derive from that that the $2^n$ outcomes are equiprobable. Hmm, now you've deleted the comment that I was replying to...